# img sizes media-condition uses rem at default size rather than based on root element

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

I have been using `:root { font-size: 62.5% }` to set `1rem == 10px` rather than the default `16px`.

However, after a lot of playing with responsive images, I note that the `img sizes` attribute media conditions seem to treat 1rem as == 16px.

The following example has two images; the first uses a default `sizes` attribute of `100vw` whilst the second uses `calc()` to subtract `10rem` from `100vw`. I've been testing this using Chrome DevTools, Device Toolbar, selecting Responsive and setting the device width to 1000 pixels.

For the first image, the browser should pick the 1000w image from `srcset`, whereas for the second image, the 840w image sets picked. This demonstrates that `1rem == 16px` as far as img sizes is concerned.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>example</title>
<style>

/**
  Much cut-down version of "The new CSS reset":
  https://github.com/elad2412/the-new-css-reset
 */

*:where(:not(html, iframe, canvas, img, svg, video, audio):not(svg *, symbol *)) {
    all: unset;
    display: revert;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    max-inline-size: 100%;
    max-block-size: 100%;
}


/**
    Page styles
 */

:root {
    font-size: 62.5%;                           /* Assuming default of 16px, sets 1rem == 10px */
}

body { font-size: 1.8rem; }                     /* =18px */
h1 { font-size: 2.8rem; font-weight: bold; }    /* =28px */

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>example</h1>

<article>

<p>The heading above and this paragraph are sized 2.8rem and 1.8rem
respectively, which equates to 28px and 18px because the root element has
a font-size of 62.5% which results in 1rem == 10px.</p>
<p>However, the sizes attribute of the img tag seems to use the default
of 1rem = 16px.</p>

<img alt=""
    src="//placehold.co/200x100/a7f/111.png"
    sizes="100vw"
    srcset="//placehold.co/800x400/7af/111.png 800w,
            //placehold.co/830x415/7af/111.png 830w,
            //placehold.co/840x420/7af/111.png 840w,
            //placehold.co/850x425/7af/111.png 850w,
            //placehold.co/900x450/7af/111.png 900w,
            //placehold.co/950x475/7af/111.png 950w,
            //placehold.co/1000x500/7af/111.png 1000w,
            //placehold.co/1400x700/7af/111.png 1400w"
>

<img alt=""
    src="//placehold.co/200x100/a7f/111.png"
    sizes="calc(100vw - 10rem)"
    srcset="//placehold.co/800x400/af7/111.png 800w,
            //placehold.co/830x415/af7/111.png 830w,
            //placehold.co/840x420/af7/111.png 840w,
            //placehold.co/850x425/af7/111.png 850w,
            //placehold.co/900x450/af7/111.png 900w,
            //placehold.co/950x475/af7/111.png 950w,
            //placehold.co/1000x500/af7/111.png 1000w,
            //placehold.co/1400x700/af7/111.png 1400w"
>

</article>

</body>
</html>
```

To be fair, this *does* make sense to me (retrospectively) in that otherwise the browser would need to download and parse all CSS prior to being able to download any images. But it was also somewhat unexpected before hand, and adds further complexity to dealing with responsive images!

I have read a lot of articles/specs regarding responsive images, but thus far I've not seen anything that mentions this particular issue. Can anyone point me to anything that specifies this behaviour?

FYI Chrome and Firefox do both behave the same in this respect so I'm sure it is correct behaviour!

A related questionette is, should I stick with the default `1rem == 16px` to avoid this type of confusion?